# Is it necessary to recreate the relationships in MS Access after linking to online database?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, relational-database

I have an Access front-end and a MySQL back-end.

After linking the MySQL tables I noticed that the relationships window in MS Access was empty. Is it necessary to recreate relationships in Access, based on foreign keys. If yes, what are the benefits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it necessary to recreate relationships in Access

No. The relationships window is empty, because Access isn't responsible for any of those relationships.  If foreign key references exist in the MySQL back end, all those constraints will be enforced by the MySQL server.

Comment: So, Access offers no benefits when creating relationships in the relationships window?

Comment: It offers a lot of benefits if you're using native Access tables. But you're not doing that. (If you had an Access front end and an Access back end, you'd still enforce relationships in the back end.) You're using MySQL tables. You need to have MySQL enforce all the known constraints.

Comment: It is not completely without advantages to add the relationships in MS Access. While the relationships are very limited, they can save time in designing a front-end, in that relationships between two tables are automatically added in the query design window and when creating forms and subforms.